# Restarting Kernel after installing a module from Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel, modulenotfounderror

I'm installing `beautifulsoup4` with

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

After which I get the message

```
"Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2; python_version >= "3.0" in /Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (2.0.1)
```

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages."

When I type

```
import beautifulsoup4
```

I get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-e646caa245dd> in <module>
----> 1 import beautifulsoup4

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beautifulsoup4'
```

Apparently, I need to restart the Kernel but I don't know what this means as I'm a new Jupyter and Python user. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you can restart by selecting Kernel > Restart from the notebook GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by setting up the kernel after installing a new package.

```
conda activate your_env
conda install package
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=your_env
```

Reference: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html